# Is this correct way to implement MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm, datagrid

I'm creating an application that enables a user to insert, update and delete data that has been entered and then shown in a data-grid (CRUD operations).

In my View Model, it contains properties which are bound to the xaml (`Firstname` for example). It also contains a navigation property as well as validation attributes.

```
      [Required(ErrorMessage = "First Name is a required field")]
      [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z''-'\s]{1,20}$", ErrorMessage = "First Name must       contain no more then 20 characters and contain no digits.")]
      public string FirstName
      {
        get { return _FirstName; }
        set
        {
            if (_FirstName == value)
                return;

            _FirstName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("FirstName");
        }
    }
```

Furthermore, it contains commands for the `xaml` to execute, which creates an instance of the CRUD operation;

```
    private void UpdateFormExecute()
    {
        var org = new OrganisationTypeDetail();
        UpdateOrganisationTypeDetail(org);
    }
```

And lastly, it contains the CRUD operations as well. Such as the Insert, Update and Delete.

Which leads me to my question. if I want to implement the correct MVVM way, is all this code too much for the view model to contain?

Should I use the model and create a collection within my View-model and bound that to my `xaml`? Would this be the correct way of doing it?

Should I use a Repository system for the CRUD operations? If so, how would I pass the data from the text fields through to the model to get updated?

Im new to WPF, MVVM and finding it hard to adapt without proper guidance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say that this is **a** correct way to implement MVVM, but not **the** correct way to implement MVVM.

What I mean by this is that there is no *one* correct way to implement this pattern. if you have created a ViewModel that can be bound to your View, without having any extra logic within your View (i.e. code-behind) then you have captured the essence of MVVM.

Whether or not you add more patterns and structure to your code is entirely up to you. If this is a simple application, I would keep the patterns light. Go ahead and have your ViewModel talk directly with a repository. You current code looks just fine to me in that respect.

If this is a large application, you might want to add further layers, like a service layer, data access layer. You might want to think about dependency injection.

**But** don't just adopt a pattern, or add an extra layer just because you think you should. Dependency Injection sounds cool, but in many cases it is more hassle than it is worth!

Comment: Thanks for clearing things up for me, the confusion is due to the fact that there are so many different ways, I just don't know which to follow! Also, What do you mean by "Dependency Injection"?

Answer (score 0):

For me it’s not the correct way, I think defining the properties like FirstName in view model is not good idea. view should contain model only and your view model should be wrap the model which should be bounded to XAML(if required).

Also model object creation should be completely independent of view model. View model should know only about unit operations on models and validations should be inside the model e.g in your case FirstName validations are in ViewModel means you are only limiting GUI to validate the FirstName property, but what if someone set it from other place.

Comment: Thanks for that. If I want to use attribute validation then, where would I put that? In the model? So from what you saying, bind the properties from the model directly to the view?

Comment: Can you describe why it is not a good idea? And why it is not 'correct' MVVM? Blindly following rules about how you should implement a pattern are as bad as not using a pattern at all!

Comment: @coline because in the explained example, FirstName seems to be a property of a model which i think should be in model only not in view model.

Comment: @D J, if that is the case, how would I bind my text fields within the xaml to the properties in the model? Also, would I still be able to use attribute validation within the model?

Comment: @gregory.bmclub you can bind the property of model like `<TextBlock Text="{Binding CustomerObject.FirstName}"/>` where CustomerObject is a model which is refered in your viewmodel and for validations there are many ways one of them is shown here at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15239/Validation-in-Windows-Presentation-Foundation.